# How to wake up an app on push notification when an app is in background

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2

Is there any way to launch an app when push notification is received from background?

I want to bring up a modal page (alert page with some info) when push notification is received.

I have tried to use the plugin `https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-background-mode`, but no luck. (wakeUp and unlock function do not work)

Comment: I've been looking for this for months. I haven't found something suitable. My App acts like an alarm but triggered remotely. I'll answer this post if I find the solution. Greetings!